# PayFort paymentAPI "Missing Parameter" for Apple Pay payment

Tags: ios, applepay, payfort

I am integrating PayFort Apple Pay in my app using PayFort Apple Pay Guide Documentation received by PayFort.

I am send all the mandatory parameters as mentioned in the documentation with same type of values.

But I'm always getting the PayFort response as "Missing Parameter".

I couldn't get the specific parameter which is missing or any error or what am I doing wrong.

These are the params that i am sending in post:

[image]

and those two params are in list: "apple_header" and "apple_paymentMethod"

[image]

Comment: have you read there documentation ?

Comment: https://docs.payfort.com/docs/mobile-sdk/build/index.html#before-starting-the-integration

Comment: are you sending sdk_token?

Comment: i couldn't find any param named sdk_token in Apple Pay PayFort Documentation Guide

Comment: I've resolve this issue by changing payfort callback method for ApplePay.. there is a different callback method for ApplePay which is not mentioned in their documentation.

Comment: okay thanks :) for note.

Comment: answer your question so anyone can find it if stuck  ... :)

Comment: What is the Payfort callback method for ApplePay?

Comment: @TahirPasha did u solved ur issue ??

Comment: Yes I'd solved the issue by adding Payfort Apple Pay callback method. You guys can found the solution in the answers

Answer (score 1):

I've resolve this issue by changing payfort callback method for ApplePay.. there is a different callback method for ApplePay which is not mentioned in their documentation.

which is

```
- (void)callPayFortForApplePayWithRequest:(NSMutableDictionary *)RequestFort
           applePayPayment:(PKPayment *)payment
     currentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
                   Success:(PAYFORTTransactionSuccess)success
                     Faild:(PAYFORTTransactionFaild)faild;
```

Comment: Hello Tahir, I am trying with Apple paySDK and I have added all the parameters mentioned into the document but still, I am getting Missing parameter error. Can you please guide me to resolve this issue

Comment: Use Apple Pay callback method for using Apple Pay

Answer (score 0):

Please Check following are mandatory parameters to do a post request with PayFort i think **"sdk_token"** is missing in your case.
[image]

Comment: there is no sdk_token param in their apple pay documentation.

Comment: can you send me the link you  or reference ?

Comment: why don't you give it a try ?

Comment: i tried it, but couldn't resolve the issue. I've also sent an email to payfort about the issue.

Comment: let request = NSMutableDictionary.init()
request.setValue("1000", forKey: "amount") request.setValue("AUTHORIZATION", forKey: "command") request.setValue("USD", forKey: "currency") request.setValue("email@domain.com", forKey: "customer_email") request.setValue("en", forKey: "language") request.setValue("112233682686", forKey: "merchant_reference") request.setValue("gr66zzwW9" , forKey: "token_name") request.setValue("" , forKey: "payment_option")...... sdk_token is replaced token_name can you check ?